# Normalizacion de valor con bigdecimal en Java

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

Busco la forma de aplicar una normalizacion a un valor como bigdecimal en Java, dado este valor double **12345678912345678923434223423.70** indicando como :

BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(**12345678912345678923434223423.70**);

Donde el valor que obtenemos es : **1.2345678912345679E+28**

¿Es posible obtener el valor original sin la normalizacion E+28 como bigdecimal?

Comment: Prueba con el método [`toPlainString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29).

Comment: Aplicando el metodo toPlainString() sobre BigDecimal a la salida obtengo este resultado 12345678912345679000000000000.

Comment: Mejor usa el constructor que recibe una cadena: `BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("12345678912345678923434223423.70");`